# Combining Normal Wordpress Post Loop with WP_User_Query

Tags: wordpress

Can someone tell me if its possible to combine a normal wordpress loop (post) with the users?
So that on the Homepage for example it will loop through both post and user profiles?

I've read up on WP_User_Query and I was hoping I could use this with WP_Query or something.

What I'm trying to do is have both post and user profiles show up on the homepage and in search results.

any ideas, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Surely you'd just this for the users?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors

`<?php wp_list_authors( $args ); ?>`

Comment: but how could I use this as part of a loop? So that authors are mixed in with posts? I thought this would just list all my authors? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite understanding you. You want to have a mixture of posts and authors in the same list?

Comment: Yes, So on the homepage for example, you would see posts and authors together from the same loop.